# [TrendingView][Pine script] Percentage change - How to show the [%] change between: close(current bar) - close(previous bar to(first chart's bar))?

Tags: pine-script

Not sure if this question was already asked; so I'll ask it again:
I'm new to TrendingView. I've noticed that the ticker of the percent refers to the difference between: the close price of the current/ last bar in the chart - the opening price of the first bar of the chart. It is not accurate to calculate this way, because, for example - if I'm on a "1D" chart of some NASDAQ stock: the default percent ticker will show the difference between: TODAY'S CURRENT CLOSE price - TODAY'S 09:30 OPENING price. Instead, it should show the difference between: TODAY'S CURRENT CLOSE price - YESTERDAY'S 16:00 CLOSE price.

I've already wrote a Pine script for the corrected percentage change for "1D" granularity (today's current bar close - yesterday's close), but I want to GENERALIZE it so the ticker will be DYNAMIC to each chart's time frame.
So I need to access the close price of the last/ current bar and the close price of the previous bar next to the first bar shown in the chart (i.e. usually the first bar in the chart is the leftmost bar in the chart (if the chart is from left to right), so I need to access the LEFT BAR CLOSEST TO THE LEFTMOST BAR SHOWN in the chart).
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `time` value of the leftmost bar shown by using `chart.left_visible_bar_time`.

Using this, you can have the `close` price of that bar by comparing the `time` value, and assign the `close` price if both are equal. From there it's just simple math:

```
//@version=5
indicator("roc", overlay=true)

var float left_bar_close = na

if time == chart.left_visible_bar_time 
    left_bar_close := close

roc = ((close / left_bar_close) - 1) * 100

plot(roc)
```

EDIT:

Using the same code, if you want to get the `close` price of the bar which is "left" to leftmost visible bar, you can use the history reference:

```
//@version=5
indicator("roc", overlay=true)

var float left_to_the_left_bar_close = na

if time == chart.left_visible_bar_time 
    left_to_the_left_bar_close := close[1]

roc = ((close / left_to_the_left_bar_close) - 1) * 100

plot(roc)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it refers to the left visible bar. How to get the time of the closest bar to it from the left ("left to-`left_visible_bar`")?

Comment: You can simply identify the leftmost bar and then get the `close` price of the previous bar using the history reference - `close[1]`. I've edited my answer so you can see it more clearly